# Multiple dataframes stored in dictionary - Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have different csv and excel files to load in pandas and I was wondering to dynamically create the load structure (example: `df1 = pd.read_csv(xxxxx)`)
so I'm looping thru the files and creating the command and storing them in a dictionary.

The problem the dictionary is storing the values as string and from there I can load the csv files and go thru the dataframe.

It's working if I use exec and eval but I'm looking for alternatives.
so far:
to create the command.

```
for i in list1:
     df_dic[calendar.month_abbr[int(i[4:6])]] = ''.join('''df_lst_'''+calendar.month_abbr[(int(i[4:6]))]+''' = pd.read_excel(r'''+"'"+dir1+i+"'"+','+'sheet_name='''''Data'''"'"+')')
```

then I'm creating a new dict only with the based only on the `df_list[X]` to manipulate it later but again it is been stored as a string.
I've tried different approaches (ast.literal_eval for example, which is giving me `ValueError: malformed node or string` ). I'm stuck

Any ideas?

Appreciate any help.

Cheers

Comment: Hi @notArobot, welcome to SO. What do you want to do with the dataframes after loading them?, how are you going to identify them?

Comment: hi @JorgeLavín, the usual, concatenate with some other dfs (with diff info), filter, create some charts and so on... My plan is to create another dic to identify them later, not sure if any of this make sense....lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May you try this

```
def load_csvs(*paths):
    dfs = {}
    for path in paths:
        dfs[path] = pd.read_csv(path)
    return dfs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    paths = ['foo.csv', 'bar.csv']
    dfs = load_csvs(paths)
    # Access the foo.csv dataframe as foo_df
    foo_df = dfs['foo.csv']
```

You can access the dataframes via its paths to manipulate them and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict comprehensions:

```
import pandas as pd
paths = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']
dfs = {p: pd.read_csv(p) for p in paths}
```

If you also want to read Excel files is the same command, you can use

```
paths = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'excel_file.xls']
dfs = {p: pd.read_csv(p) if p.endswith('.csv') else pd.read_excel(p) for p in paths}
```

@jorge's solution with the loop has the advantage that you can wrap each `read_csv` in a try-catch block, so you can handle corrupt files.